# How to translate this Condition into SQL language?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, where-clause

I'm using SQL SERVER 2012 and my database is related to guests in an hotel. I need to write a query that will extract data related to guests who spent their holidays in a particular month, say, May 2014.
The 2 columns that will filter the data for me are the DateOfArrival and DateOfDeparture. 
I just can't figure out how to write the WHERE clause that will give me the data for May 2014.

I've tried this one (but then figured out that it is flawed):

```
WHERE DateOfDeparture BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31'
```

It is flawed because I will miss the guests whose date of departure is **AFTER** 2014-05-31 but who arrived within the month of MAY 2014 (eg: DateOfArrival 2014-05-26 and DateOfDeparture 2014-06-03).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking down the question, you need to find people that arrived before the end date AND departed after the start date. This makes the clause look like this:

```
WHERE DateOfArrival <= '2014-05-31' AND DateOfDeparture >= '2014-05-01'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just amend:

```
WHERE (DateOfDeparture BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31') OR (DateOfArrival BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats pretty tricky when you think about all possible cases, let's say someone arrives `'20140429'` but departs `'20140603'`. Here is what i've got so far, probably can be optimezed, need some time to figure out how:

```
WHERE '20140501' BETWEEN DateOfArrival AND DateOfDeparture
   OR '20140531' BETWEEN DateOfArrival AND DateOfDeparture
   OR DateOfArrival BETWEEN '20140501' AND '20140531'
```

One more thing: I noted you're using non-standard date format `'2014-05-01'`. Try to avoid it as you may face issues related to local settings. Standard date format in SQL Server is YYYYMMDD.

Comment: Seems rather complicated. Also using YYYY-MM-DD is not going to cause any localisation issues, it's exactly the same as YYYYMMDD

Comment: You are correct, I made it more complicated than necessary, your approach is much better.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,DateOfDeparture,102) BETWEEN '2014-07-01' AND '2014-07-31'
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.